# Checking an array for an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am putting an array ($row) in another array ($allRows):

```
array_push($allRows, $row);
```

Is there an easy way to check if an array already exists in $allRows?

Comment: What do you mean? [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
if (in_array($array1, $array2)) {
echo "Array found";
}
// $array1 - needle.
```

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! Perfect...didnt know that in_array can do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [`in_array`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if (in_array($row, $allRows, TRUE)) {
   echo "Array found";
}
```

In difference to the existing answer, this one actually tells you the order of parameters and that it's necessary that you specify the *strict* parameter.

Otherwise you would be comparing something else which most likely is not what you're looking for, see [*Comparison Operators*<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)...

```
$range = range(1, 10);

var_export(in_array($range, array(range(1, 10))));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/pJLeKoZg).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if $allRows already have elements with

```
count($allRows)
```